# Best Way to Debug html5lib.html5parser.ParseError: Unexpected character after attribute value"?

Tags: python, html, attributes, python-chess, html5lib

I am currently working on a personal project and utilizing the chessdotcom Public API Package. I am currently able to store in a variable the PGN from the daily puzzle (Portable Game Notation) which is a required input to create a chess gif (https://www.chess.com/gifs).

I wanted to use requests and html parsers to essentially fill out the form on the gifs site and create a gif through my python script. I made a request to the gif website and the response.text returns a huge html string (thousands of lines) which I am parsing using html5lib. I am currently getting a "html5lib.html5parser.ParseError: Unexpected character after attribute value." I can't seem to figure out where in this giant response the issue is. What are some tips/tricks to debug this issue? Where do I even begin looking for this unexpected character?

```
import requests as req
import html5lib
from datetime import datetime
from chessdotcom import Client, get_player_profile, get_player_game_archives,get_player_stats, get_current_daily_puzzle, get_player_games_by_month


Client.request_config['headers']['User-Agent'] = 'PyChess Program for Automated YouTube Creation'


class ChessData:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.player = get_player_profile(name)
        self.archives = get_player_game_archives(name)
        self.stats = get_player_stats(name)
        self.games = get_player_games_by_month(name, datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month)
        self.puzzle = get_current_daily_puzzle()
        self.html_parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(strict=True, namespaceHTMLElements=True, debug=True)

    def organize_puzzles(self, puzzles):
        #dict_keys(['title', 'url', 'publish_time', 'fen', 'pgn', 'image'])
        portableGameNotation = puzzles['pgn']
        html_data = req.get('https://www.chess.com/gifs')
        print(html_data.text)
        self.html_parser.parse(html_data.text.replace('&', '&amp;'))

    def get_puzzles(self):
        self.organize_puzzles(self.puzzle.json['puzzle'])
```

I had initially had issues with "Name Entity Expected. Got None" error which I temporarily bypassed by replacing all instances of `&` with `&amp;` entity.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ChessProgram/ChessTop.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/ChessProgram/ChessTop.py", line 14, in main
    ChessResults.get_puzzles()
  File "C:\ChessProgram\ChessData.py", line 32, in get_puzzles
    self.organize_puzzles(self.puzzle.json['puzzle'])
  File "C:\ChessProgram\ChessData.py", line 29, in organize_puzzles
    self.html_parser.parse(html_data.text.replace('&', '&amp;'))
  File "C:\ChessProgram\lib\site-packages\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 284, in parse
    self._parse(stream, False, None, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ChessProgram\lib\site-packages\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 133, in _parse
    self.mainLoop()
  File "C:\ChessProgram\lib\site-packages\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 216, in mainLoop
    self.parseError(new_token["data"], new_token.get("datavars", {}))
  File "C:\ChessProgram\lib\site-packages\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 321, in parseError
    raise ParseError(E[errorcode] % datavars)
html5lib.html5parser.ParseError: Unexpected character after attribute value.
```

I tried replacing the `&` with `&amp;` to fix the entity name issue and manually searched through this html response for the different attributes and looking for anything out of place.

Comment: `html` may use `&` in many places - ie. `&gt;`, `&lt;`, `&copy;`, etc. - so replacing all `&` with `&amp;` may create wrong values.

Comment: i don't know why you parse this page. Normally it needs only to use `request.post()` to send data to page - to simulate filled form. And later you may need to parse page with result. But maybe it will need only to find link to GIF using standard functions for string - without parsing all HTML.

Comment: I see other problem. It uses `cookies` and it send unique `token` in form. It may need to use `requests.Session` and `get` first page with form to get `cookies`. But it may have more complex system to block scripts/bots and it may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser.

Comment: I created working code but I used `beautifulsoup` to get token, and later I used normal `text.find()` to get url to image.

Comment: use `html5lib.HTMLParser()` without parameters (or with `stricte=False`) and it will work without `.replace('&', '&amp;')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally to debug html I would try to split HTML to smaller elements and test it. But with `html5lib` it may be problem because it may need full HTML to parse it. So it may need to write own functions in parser to display more information during parsing.

But if you use `html5lib.HTMLParser()` without parameters (or with `stricte=False`) then it runs correctly even without `.replace('&', '&amp;')`

But still I wouldn't use `html5lib` for this because I don't see any functions to search elements in HTML. It may need to write own functions.

It is much simpler to do it with `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` (or other modules)

---

Other problem: page uses cookies and it has hidden `input` with `token` which it probably compares with cookies (to generate image) and this needs `requests.Session()

So I do

- create `requests.Session()`
- use session to `get()` page with `form`
- use `BeautifulSoup` to search hidden `input` with `token`
- use session to `post()` all data like real `form`
- use standard `text.find()` to find url to `animated gif`
  (it has unique address - so it is easy to find it without `BeautifulSoup`)
- use session to `get()` `aniamted gif` and write it in local file
  (it needs `.content` instead of `.text` to work with `bytes` instead of `string`)
- (optional) use `webbrowser` to display url with `animated gif` in default browser
  (if local image viewer has problem to display animated gifs)

Full working code:

```
#import requests 
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

#headers = {
#    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0' 
#}    

s = Session()
#s.headers.update(headers)

url = 'https://www.chess.com/gifs'

# --- get token ---

response = s.get(url)
html = response.text

#soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

item = soup.find('input', {'id': 'animated_gif__token'})
#print(item)

token = item['value']
print('token:', token)

# --- send form, get response and search image ---

game =  "https://www.chess.com/live/game/3048628857"

payload = {
    "animated_gif[data]": game,
    "animated_gif[board_texture]": "green", # "brown",
    "animated_gif[piece_theme]": "neo",
    "animated_gif[_token]": token
}

response = s.post(url, data=payload)
html = response.text

start = html.find('https://images.chesscomfiles.com/uploads/game-gifs/')
end   = html.find('"', start)

image_url = html[start:end]

print(image_url)

# --- download file ---

response = s.get(image_url)

# write using `bytes` instead of `text`
with open('animation.gif', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)

# --- show image_url in browser ---

import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(image_url)
```

Comment: Thank you for your indepth answer. I had to inspect the html page to understand how you knew the payload should reference "animated_gif".  I was able to get the auto creation of the daily puzzle thanks to yourcode. And I wasn't aware of this hidden token. Is this always the case when the page uses cookies?

Comment: I used built-in `DevTools` (tab: `Network`) in `Firefox` or `Chrome` to see what browser sends to server. And it shows all needed fields without checking `HTML` :) Some pages send `token` in `cookies` without hidden field, some pages use hidden fields, some pages don't use `token` at all. BTW: I have only on video which shows work with `DevTool` in `Firefox` but without sound and without text. You have to observe mouse. And it doesn't show that it needs to press `F12` on keyboard to activate `DevTools`.  [DevTools to find JSON data in EpicGames](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvvWQ9qWOmI)

Comment: and I have code for other my answers on Stackoverflow for different pages (using `request`, `beautifulsoup` or `Selenium` or `scrapy`: [GitHub: furas / python-examples / \_\_scraping\_\_](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__/)